# Azure AD B2C SAML Idp extract sessionIndex/sessionID from SAML assertion into OAuth2 JWT

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have integrated SAML2 Idp with Azure AD B2C. I am able to perform oAuth2 authentication and obtain id_token and access_token successfully.

I have a requirement to extract sso sessionIndex or session ID from SAML assertion into id_token/access_token. I noticed sessionIndex/ID are not coming as `<saml:Attribute>`. But it is available under `<saml:AuthnStatement>`:

```
<saml:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2018-10-30T18:28:42Z"
        SessionIndex="A659D5A1B123456BA0EA744B80CB1AFA2EB6BBD14"
        SessionNotOnOrAfter="2018-10-31T02:30:42Z">
        <saml:AuthnContext>
            <saml:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password
            </saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
        </saml:AuthnContext>
    </saml:AuthnStatement>
```

Here is my custom policy settings:

```
    <ClaimsProvider>
  <Domain>samlIdp</Domain>
  <DisplayName>samlIdp</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="samlIdpProfile">
      <DisplayName>samlIdpProfile</DisplayName>
      <Description>Login with your account</Description>
      <Protocol Name="SAML2" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="RequestsSigned">false</Item>
        <Item Key="WantsEncryptedAssertions">false</Item>
        <Item Key="WantsSignedAssertions">false</Item>
        <Item Key="PartnerEntity">https://samlIdp.com/.well-known/samlidp.xml</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="SamlAssertionSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SAMLSigningCert" />
        <Key Id="SamlMessageSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SAMLSigningCert" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="socialIdpUserId" PartnerClaimType="userId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="username" />

        <!-- newly added claims -->
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="sessionId" DefaultValue="na" PartnerClaimType="ID" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="sessionIndex" DefaultValue="na" PartnerClaimType="sessionIndex" />

      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId" />
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <!--<UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" /> -->
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Saml" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

I need to get this sessionIndex as part of my oauth2 JWT. Any help would be appreciated.